# Return to Vim after external program execution

Tags: vim

Using `vim-fugtive` I can `commit` from `Vim` itself. But to push to server, I have to do `:!git push`. It works fine (though I wish it happened in the background). After pushing to server, I get this message: `Press ENTER or type command to continue`.

Is there a way by pass and return to `Vim` without having to press any key?

Answer (score 0):

The `:!` command allows to interact with the external program; that's the reason for the *hit-enter* prompt. If you don't need interaction and want to avoid the prompt, you can prepend `:silent`:

```
:silent !git push
```

Comment: Quit surprisingly, Vim fails to redraw after this! I can press `<C-z>` and use `fg` to come back though. But it kills it. I suspect the answer is correct but perhaps my "extensive plugins" may be causing it!

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [Fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive)'s `:Gpush` command. Just execute the following:

```
:Gpush
```

After you execute `:Gpush` the quickfix list will be populated with the results of the push (open the quickfix window via `:copen`). If you have [Dispatch.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-dispatch) installed the push will occur in the background.

Note: for arbitrary git commands you can use `:Git` instead of `:!git`. e.g. `:Git stash` and `:Git checkout master`.

For more information see:

```
:h :Gpush
:h :cope
:h :Git
```